# What type of electromagnetic wave can pass through silver or aluminium standard mirror?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, reflection

I have been told (not sure if it is true), that mirror (and glass) do not allow to pass the electromagnetic signals of mobile signals.

but for a standard mirror what type of wave can pass through it?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer I provided to [this older question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1094/how-i-can-create-hindrances-to-radio-waves/2307#2307) is very applicable here. The degree to which an EM signal is obstructed will depend on the material properties of the object (conductivity, primarily) and the wavelength of the signal. For a mobile phone, the conductive metal coating of the mirror is likely much thinner than the skin depth, so the signal should only be weakened a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one type of electromagnetic wave.

A hi-frequency electromagnetic wave in the hf radio band can pass through a mirror because the mirror is seen as an antenna of a small size in comparison to wavelenth.

Comment: While it is true that all electromagnetic radiation has the same intrinsic character, its interaction with matter varies hugely depending on it's frequency, so there is some risk that thi answer could be misunderstood.