# Why can radio wave travel through walls while infrared can't?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If both radio waves and gamma rays can travel through walls](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6725/if-both-radio-waves-and-gamma-rays-can-travel-through-walls)

Does it have anything to do with the materials used to build the wall?
What determines if a material can absorb an (x) wavelength?

Comment: Possibly related to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6725/if-both-radio-waves-and-gamma-rays-can-travel-through-walls. You must also correct your "Imfrared"...

Comment: Sorry Abdel... But, Please see if there is any question related to you *here*, before posting it. And, Feel free to revise the question (for any other clearance), & flag it for moderator attention...